# Transferring git files to another branch

Tags: git, repository, move

I have some Android device source code uploaded to a git repository. The code is currently on the master branch. I want to add a different Android source code (different android version) in the same repo, but on a different branch. But, I want to categorize each source tree in its own branch.

So, what I want to do is:

1. Create new branch called cm10
2. Move all the code from master branch to cm10 branch
3. Completely delete the master branch

I am new to git, so I can only easily create a new branch (new branch called cm10 in this case), but I don't know how to do the rest.

Please also add comments on what each command does. It will be a good way for me learn more about git.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I better dont ask why you wanna do this...

```
git checkout -b cm10 // checkout cm10 branch (-b creates it)
git merge master // shoud not be neccessary when branch is created
git branch -d master // delete the master branch

// if you have remote repository too you may want to:
git push origin cm10 // create new remote branch
git push origin :master // remove master branch
```

Comment: Yes, I should have done it before. Now, I have to go through this. Anyway, I will try it and see if it works.

Comment: I am getting this while pushing the deletion of master branch:

remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To https://github.com/rqmok/android_vendor_huawei_u8800.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/rqmok/android_vendor_huawei_u8800.git'

Comment: Solved the above error. Had to go to github and set cm10 as the default branch to be able to delete the master branch.